# Java HashMap 'key' objects are stored by reference?

Tags: java, reference, hashmap

I'm using a 'Point3D' class members as Key in a HashMap, The values of the HashMap are 'Voxel' - a 3D virtual cube in space.

Now, for some reason the following code prints 'null'.

```
HashMap<Point3D,Voxel> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
Voxel v = new Voxel(new Point3D(0,0,0),200,geos);

hashMap.put(new Point3D(0,0,0),v);
Voxel test = hashMap.get(new Point3D(0,0,0));

System.out.println(v.toString());
```

**My guess is that the mapping 'Key' stored by reference, and when i send 'new' object, although it have the same values in its fields it is still not the original Key and the 'get' method return null.**

Point3D have overriding method for 'equals' and Voxel have overriding method for 'toString', i thought it might help with comparing the Key.

Am i right this is happen because of the references differences?
and if i do, please help me to find a way to map by a Point3D fields and not the reference.

Thank so much!

Comment: You need to override hashCode also

Comment: Point3D as a key is working just fine, try out that piece of code and change the Voxel to a String you put in as a value.

Comment: well it seems like you two have some dispute...
i will check the 'String' thing

Comment: Show us `Point3D`.

Comment: Point3D is a javafx class, we dont have a dispute, i am just telling you a way how you can figure out that your comment about key references is wrong.

Comment: Seiniger what you suggesting doesn't work.
thank AmitBera

Comment: HashMap<Point3D,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        String s = "hi";

        hashMap.put(new Point3D(0,0,0),s);
        s = hashMap.get(new Point3D(0,0,0));

        System.out.println(s);

will print out "hi" in your console

Comment: Ok, first this is my own Point3D, not the javafx.
This class is just three doubles, and some more method.

Comment: So, i need to override hashCode in my Point3D class ?

Comment: ohhhh well then you have to override hashCode() like the others are telling you, still my comment stating that your assumption about keys and references is wrong holds

Comment: Thanks Seiniger.
it does make more sense now (since i did a similar mapping with another javafax class and it works...)

Answer (score 1):

Java `Map` actually use `hashCode()` to indicate the keys are indentical or not. Just look over the class `Point3D`